# What kind of pattern has a class that contains an instance of itself cast to the interface?

Tags: design-patterns, interface

I have recently inherited some code, and I can't figure out the reasoning behind the architecture of one of the classes.  The class looks something like this:

```
[Serializable]
internal class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    private DbModel dataModel { get; set; }
    private MyInterface IThis { get { return (MyInterface)this; } }

    public string SomeProperty { get { return IThis.SomeProperty } }
    ...
    string MyInterface.SomeProperty { get { return dataModel.GetSomeProperty(); } }
}
```

Is this some sort of common (or uncommon) design pattern that I've just never seen?  Why would we want to access the properties this way?  What benefit do we get from this? Notice that the IThis is not static, so it isn't some sort of Singleton pattern.

Comment: This does not appear to be a pattern or architecture, it is just some "interesting" code. My guess would be that this class has done many things and been used in many ways and just has the associated history of cruft.

Comment: @dbugger: Thanks for the insight.  Unfortunately, it is a newer class that has only ever had one purpose.  Maybe the author was bored that day and wanted to try something different.

Comment: It just looked like it might have been supporting a traditional form?, and possibly someone mentioned an interface was needed.  But "bored" is also a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks somewhat like the [Snapshot variant](https://books.google.ca/books?id=810chlr-IQgC&lpg=PA89&ots=n3aY0mCARS&dq=allintext%3Amark%20grand%20patterns%20in%20java%20snapshot&pg=PA375#v=onepage&q=snapshot&f=false) of Memento, but perhaps encapsulation is being used at assembly level (hence internal). Can you see if the `Caretaker` and `Originator` roles are filled somewhere?

[image: Snapshot pattern in PlantUML]